# How to solve this ODE $y'=-\frac{1}{x-y+1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'=-\frac{1}{x-y+1}$$

It is not exact, it has no integrating factor, I couldn't separate $y$ and $x$ to integrate because $y'$ is getting multiplied by 3 things. I couldn't find any way to solve it, it's been some time already.

Comment: **Hint:** You can make it Exact.

Comment: You mean by algebraic manipulation? I tried moving the denominator to the left (multiplying $y'$) and then dividing by $xy'$, $yy'$ and $y'$. Either 3 ways I couldn't find any M and N which I could find a integrating factor. It  either was not a function only of $x$ and $y$ or it would cancel out and give me 1 as the integrating factor.

Comment: Since the original is not exact, you want to find a $\mu$ such that $\mu M + \mu N y' = 0$ is exact. We currently have $(1) dx + (x - y + 1) dy = 0$. Try $\mu = e^y$. Now, how did I figure that out?

Comment: Wow, how you thought of that? In general I just try to find a integrating factor by using the general formula and if I can't find a function of x or y I just give up the method. I didn't know you could "guess" one. In this case it seems that this works because we have a constant in M and and $y^1$ in N, when you differentiate is just 1 which makes no difference. I'll consolidate that. You got any tips? I'm bad right now at visualizing this things, I know it helps with practice, but...

Comment: At your college library, see if you can find the book Schaum's Outline for 2500 Solved Problems by Bronson. It has one of the best write-ups and summary table for NOT guessing and figuring Integrating Factors for such non-Exact Equations. Copy those pages and study them - it is very helpful!

Comment: I know i shouldn't say that but thanks Moo, you were of great help!

Comment: @JoãoPedro What?!  Saying thanks is most definitely approvable in my eyes.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere here to avoid saying "Thanks!". Never really understand it but I follow it most of times. Maybe the reason is to avoid flood of "Thanks"? Nvm, I think at least the OP has reasons to say thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{1}{x-y+1}$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=-x+y-1$$
$$x'+x=y-1$$
First order linear D.E but respect to y.

so that 
$P(y)=1$ and $Q(y)=y-1$

so the general solution is
$$x(y)=c_1e^{-y}+y-2$$

Comment: Appreciate it but I haven't learn this method yet, and my teacher only taught us using the $y'$ notation. I'm trying right now as @Moo advised me, if I can, i'll compare with this result you showed me. Thanks.

Comment: This solution is the same if you do with respect to $y$? Except that here you isolate $x$, instead of $y$?

Comment: you can do this  for first order D.E. only

Answer (score 0):

Considering the differential equation $$y'=-\frac{1}{x-y+1}$$ let us define $$z=x-y+1 \implies y=x+1-z \implies y'=1-z'$$ This leads to the new differential equation$$1-z'=-\frac 1z$$ which can rewrite $$x'=\frac z{z+1}=1-\frac 1{z+1}$$ which is totally separable. Integrating both sides $$x+C=z-\log(|z+1|)\implies x +C=x-y+1-\log(|2+x-y|)$$that is to say $$C=y+\log(|2+x-y|)$$

Sooner or later, you will learn that, using [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), we can write $$y=x+2+ W\left(C e^{-(x+2)}\right)$$